# virtual keyboard jquery incorrect display in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, virtual-keyboard

I have used jquery virtual keyboard for bootstrap modal box field. And I want to display keyboard after the text field in modal box after focus on text field.

JQuery code is

```
$('#test').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty', usePreview: false,position: {
        // null = attach to input/textarea;
        // use $(sel) to attach elsewhere
        of: $('#teste'),
        my: 'center top',
        at: 'center top',
        // used when "usePreview" is false
        at2: 'center bottom'
      } });
```

Bootstrap modalbox code is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Contact Information</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="test" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="test" placeholder="test" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="save" >Send</button>
  </div>
</div></form>
```

Here is the demo url http://jsfiddle.net/5Lww1wgm/3/
May be position is absolute so it is not displaying keyboard properly.
Thanks,

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because `$('#teste')` doesn't exist (at least in the jsfiddle), so the position gets set to 0, 0 (left, top) - here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lww1wgm/4/) that uses `$('#test')` instead, or just completely remove the position option and it should work as @jjs2000 shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fiddle link is missing jQuery ui, I suggest that you may be missing these in your project because when I added them to your fiddle it started working in the correct manner after also changing the initialization code to remove the position variables so it looks like so

```
 $('#test').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty', usePreview: false});
```

hope this fixes your issue

Edit 1:

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jjr2000/88zg4n3e/1/

Comment: jQuery UI is included in my project and I want to display keyboard  after text field and your suggestion is not working.

Comment: Have you made sure to include both the jQuery-ui css and js files? also since your fiddle is very bare bones it's hard to tell if the issue is being caused by another part of your own css, script files or html layout

Comment: There is virtual keyboard position issue not jquery UI. And you can check virtual keyboard demo too for issue.Anyway, updated fiddle.

Comment: Please review the fiddle in my edit that shows it working as you have not made the jQuery changes in your fiddle

Comment: Thanks and if i rotate with transform: rotate(90deg). here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88zg4n3e/2/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for asking on Stack Overflow.

Apologies for not commenting, but I don't have enough reputation.

I can't tell as this jsfiddle playground doesn't include all your bootstrap layout, however, it looks like it's been dynamically positioned. This is both a bad solution and ugly.

If possible (I haven't used the jQuery virtual keyboard before), I would suggest you follow these steps:

- create an empty invisible div above or below the textbox
- On loadup Inject the JQuery keybaord into this div
- On textbox focus, make this div visible. On LoseFocus, make it invisible.

Hope this helps

Comment: There is inbuilt issue of jquery virtual keyboard. Can you give me demo what you have suggested? As i have tried this already and not working.

Comment: Hi @BhumiShah, thanks for replying. I've forked your JSFiddle and updated it on my account. However, this was a much mopre in-depth option that originally anticipated. However, I've managed to fix it now :). Please see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rhysoc/ko6rufej/9/)